# Report period - add addtional selection "week"

Tags: grid, reports, date

I want to extend the period selection (day,month,year) with an option "week".

I can add following function to my Grid.php:

```
public function getPeriods()
{
    return array(
        'day' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Day'),
        'week' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Week'),
        'month' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Month'),
        'year' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Year')
    );
}
```

This makes the week option to show up in the selection.

And it looks like `app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Helper/Data.php` is handling the selection in `getIntervals($from, $to, $period = self::REPORT_PERIOD_TYPE_DAY)`

Do I have to overwrite this function? Isn't there any better solution possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with adding the getIntervals() function to my custom collection class. For calculating the week I extended the switch statement with:

```
case 'week':
$t['title'] = $dateStart->toString(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat());
$t['start'] = $dateStart->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$t['end'] = $dateStart->toString('yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59');
$dateStart->addDay(7);
$t['end'] = $dateStart->toString('yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59');
break;
```

Works for me :)